# Do <stream>.toTable().toStream() returns the original stream with old records with same key removed?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KStream` which can contain duplicate records. I can remove the old records with same key by using `.groupByKey().reduce()` but wanted to know if I can achieve this through `.toTable().toStream()` as well or not?

My understanding is that `.toTable()` will return a `KTable` containing only the latest records & applying `.toStream()` on it will give a stream of latest records with old records with same key deleted. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can achieve the same result by using a KTable, but take in your consideration that using the KTable will create a rocks DB table and an extra topic called "change log topic" and this DB table will be in synchronization with the change log topic.

All the changes applied in the KTable will be sent to change log topic, that will make the re-creation of the table easy in case if the db was deleted for any reason.

As mentioned in the KafkaStreams API documentation :

> KTable is an abstraction of a changelog stream from a primary-keyed
> table. Each record in this changelog stream is an update on the
> primary-keyed table with the record key as the primary key. A KTable
> is either defined from a single Kafka topic that is consumed message
> by message or the result of a KTable transformation. An aggregation of
> a KStream also yields a KTable.
>
> A KTable can be transformed record by record, joined with another
> KTable or KStream, or can be re-partitioned and aggregated into a new
> KTable.

More details about the Ktable API [here](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html).